# Why is nginx root path cannot be found anywhere in local machine and container?

Tags: nginx

My company use docker to deploy the environments and one container is the nginx container. I'm starting to learn and I'm confused about a small thing:

Below is part of the `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
      ...

    server {
        listen 8003 default_server;
        listen [::]:8003 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
```

I'm confused about `root /var/www/html;` since `/var/www/html` does not exist in my local machine and it also does not exist in the nginx container. 
Nothing is wrong because the environment is working fine. 
What is `/var/www/html` then, if it exists nowhere?

Comment: Just to be sure - how have you checked that it does not exist in the container?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  Inside the nginx container,  I went to the directory `/var` and `www` does not even exist.

Comment: When troubleshooting, it makes sense to go back and verify all the info you have, which is why I asked. But to do that properly you need to carefully check *how* you got that info.  `Inside the nginx container` doesn't tell me which container, or how you "got inside".  `I went to the directory` does not tell me what you did or how.  If you are 1000% confident those things are correct, fair enough, forget this and move on. From my POV you didn't verify the info I was trying to confirm, so I still wonder if there isn't a chance you're looking in the wrong place, or misinterpreting something.

Comment: Another possibility - maybe the config you've shown is the default server, but your not actually using it and are using a vhost, configured somewhere else?  nginx vhost configs are usually in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, could there be a config with a different document root in there?

Comment: What i answered plus what he said. Also, and only as a note, "default server" actualy is "default_server" inside a "listen" config  line.

Answer (score 0):

There must be [eo]ither 'root'/'alias' directive somewhere OR..

Another possible thing is that nginx is started with command line arguments, using/defining/applying of relevant [-c (file) / -g (directives) / -p (prefix)] configuration bits.

running the container with `nginx -T` will output config as it is loaded/parsed from files

Also, you say you cannot see the path in the container... my question is this, have you checked all of the container's volumes and/or images? They could very well contain the paths you are looking for.

`docker inspect container_name` could help

You could also try to get the information another way... add this to the server block

```
    location /test {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html;
    }
```

This simply tells nginx to use the folder /var/www/html for the location /test (as well as for whatever it is already set for). Using the auto index feature, you can then investigate a little bit. Per example, you might find some files there that will give you a hint as to what is going on...

All in all, i want to assure you that, even tho i lack the proper information from your specific case to make a slam dunk as to what is going on, i can assure you that there is absolotely no spell-casting or sorcery involved with this...

There is, unfortunately (for you), alot of ways one could go about finding typical/basic stuff/variables from such an env config.

Please. Let us know as it might/will help others in the future!

Thanks for Hasssking